# How to use git branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

being new to git, I have this dumb question - what is the correct way of using feature-branches ?

From what I have gathered, this is how I thought it should be used:

got some 'develop' branch from which branches are checked out:

```
"feature-1"
"feature-2"
"feature-3"
```

etc.

Now, one or more developers would work on one or more feature branches, and when the team leader wants to glue everything back together and test he would then merge the features back into the 'develop' trunk. 
However, git appears to lack the ability to hand pick what changes to keep from each feature branch (tried recursive, patience and every other merge strategy) so in the end, sometimes each of the branch ends up overwriting what previous branches merged back into 'develop'.
Things get even nastier as developers continue to work on their branches and team leader attempts to merge them into 'develop' from time to time to incorporate the changes.

Obviously this is not the right way to branch-for-feature. But what is the right way then ?

thanks

EDIT:

Just to illustrate further, let's consider we have these files in develop branch:

```
fileA (develop)
fileB (develop)
fileC (develop)
```

Now merge back in "feature-1" which only touches fileA:

```
fileA (conflict, theoretically solvable by the recursive/theirs strategy)
fileB (develop)
fileC (develop)
```

Next merge back "feature-2" that only touches fileB:

```
fileA (overwritten by feature-2!!!)
fileB (conflict, theoretically solvable by the recursive/theirs strategy)
fileC (develop)
```

What to do about fileA ? I would want it to keep the "feature-1" version of it.

Comment: It is the "right way", just merge it correctly and all will be fine.

Comment: This may degenerate into an opinion-type discussion, but I'm not sure enough to flag it. Personally I think "how to do branching in git" is a religious discussion. If you can rewrite it into "we would like to do branching in git in a-b-c way, but we're getting x-y-z errors", you'll be more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: @zerkms Care  to comment my edit ?

Comment: @shoover In spite git being touted on every street, I find it pretty immature if this question is able to start flame wars.

Comment: "fileA (overwritten by feature-2!!!)" --- how is it possible? If `fileA` wasn't changed in `F-2` it will be left untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you haven't tried what you're asking about and just making assumptions about how it may work.

If that's true - then your assumptions are not correct. When you merge 2 branches in git - it calculates the diff between the source branch beginning and the `HEAD` (or any other changeset you're merging with) and applies it to the destination changeset.

So following your example - `fileA` will not be modified in any way when you merge `feature-2` just because it wasn't modified in `feature-2`.

So there is no issue at all.

Comment: all right... well, in my noobness, who knows what knobs i have turned and blew gaskets ? Just tell me how can I see what got changed in any ways after a merge please

Comment: I think git diff HEAD^ did it.